# RavenDB: efficient enough?

Tags: ravendb, non-relational-database

My boss asked me to think about migrating to a non-relational database like RavenDB. As I understand, I would have to rewrite in C# all my stored procedures. Could you please tell me if using RavenDB is a good idea, and would it be efficient enough?

Thanks.

Comment: Comparing to using stored procedures in relational databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is ambiguous. Comparing RavenDb to SQL on the matter of efficiency is not relevant. Efficiency itself is ambiguous here. However..!

A well designed Lucene index (basic/core mechanics of RavenDb) will likely perform better than a stored procedure (especially if infested with logic). So basically, potentially faster.

Also, it will help extracting that logic (if any) to where it belongs.

The C# API is amazing...

Comment: Actually, I am trying to compare SQL not to RavenDB, but to RavenDB + C# (instead of stored procedures). Thanks anyway.\

Answer (score 2):

David,
You won't have to write stored procedures to use RavenDB, and it is highly efficient and scalable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you mean, it is efficient even if C# code is responsible for the logic that otherwise would be maintained by stored procedures? Because we do use stored procedures with our relational database.

Comment: RavenDB is not scalable. You have to pay for every new instance.